# Embed a excel/html/pdf file into a pdf file

Tags: excel, pdf-generation

Is it possible to add a excel or static html page or another pdf file into another pdf document? When I say add, I mean can I see a excel/html/pdf icon from a pdf page and open it? 
I tried to lookup the options, I only found merging pdfs options which is not what im looking for.

TIA

Comment: yes, they are file attachments and it is possible

Answer (score 1):

[CPDF](http://community.coherentpdf.com/) can do this:

```
cpdf -attach-file [-to-page n] <filename-of-attachment> input.pdf -o output.pdf
```

For example

```
cpdf -attach-file file.html -to-page 4 in.pdf -o out.pdf
```